# MongoDB in spring web project

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am writing a web project in spring 3.1.0, and I am using mongodb 1.0.0.RELEASE.

I need to get the MongoTemplate object into the controller without opening unnecessary new connections, something like a pool? How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoTemplate uses MongoDB java driver which does connection pooling. You could optionally configure the number of connections, timeouts, etc.